# Template overloaded operator in Eigen::Matrix

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, eigen3

I got this basic code working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using T12 = Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>;
using T22 = Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2>;

template <typename Der1, typename Der2> T22
operator^ (const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der1>& d1, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der2>& d2) {
  return d1 * d2.transpose();
}

void testT12DyadT12 () {
  T12 t12_1, t12_2;
  t12_1 << 2.0, 3.0;  t12_2 << 1.5, 2.5;

  const double c1{2.0}, c2{0.5};
  T22 t22_1 = c1*t12_1 ^ t12_2*c2;
  std::cout << t22_1 << "\n"; 
}

int main () {
  testT12DyadT12();
  //testT1nDyadT1n ();
  return 0;
}
```

This works and produces the correct `2 x 2` matrix output. Now I want to templatize the number of rows and columns in the matrix as

```
template<int nc>
using T1n = Eigen::Matrix<double, nc, 1>;
template<int nc>
using T2n = Eigen::Matrix<double, nc, nc>;

template <int nc, typename Der1, typename Der2> T2n<nc>
operator& (const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der1>& d1, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der2>& d2) {
  return d1 * d2.transpose();
}

void testT1nDyadT1n () {
  T1n<2> t12_1, t12_2;
  t12_1 << 2.0, 3.0;  t12_2 << 1.5, 2.5;

  T2n<2> t22_1 = t12_1 & t12_2;
  std::cout << t22_1 << "\n"; 
}
```

But it gives this compiler error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('T1n<2>' (aka 'Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>') and 'T1n<2>')
T2n<2> t22_1 = t12_1 & t12_2;
               ~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'nc'
operator& (const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der1>& d1, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der1>& d2) {
^
```

I understand the error message (that the compiler is not able to infer the template arg). *How do I fix this*? I tried passing the args to the operator as `const Der1&, const Der2&`, to no avail. I am sure it's something silly ... that I have not understood or paid attention to. Eventually my goal is to templatize Eigen scalar type as well: `template< typename T, int nc > using T1n = Eigen::Matrix<T, nc, 1>;` etc., and overload `operator^`.

Comment: Why do you think you need `int nc` in the `operator&` template arguments? `nc` is not used anywhere else in the template, so it cannot be deduced. You need to use something like `const Eigen::Matrix<T, nc, nc2>& d1` as your function arguments if you need `nc`. But why not just omit it?

Comment: [n. 'pronouns' m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-pronouns-m) - agreed, the easiest way is to return with `auto` as in the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive the size of the return type from `Der1::RowsAtCompileTime`:

```
template <typename Der1, typename Der2> 
T2n<Der1::RowsAtCompileTime>
operator& (const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der1>& d1, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der2>& d2) {
  return d1 * d2.transpose();
}
```

Or fully generic (assuming `Der1` and `Der2` have the same scalar type):

```
template <typename Der1, typename Der2> 
Eigen::Matrix<typename Der1::Scalar, Der1::RowsAtCompileTime, Der2::RowsAtCompileTime>
operator& (const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der1>& d1, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der2>& d2) {
  return d1 * d2.transpose();
}
```

With C++14 you could of course just return `auto` (this will return a lazy expression, which may or may not be what you expect):

```
template <typename Der1, typename Der2> 
auto
operator& (const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der1>& d1, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Der2>& d2) {
  return d1 * d2.transpose();
}
```

Comment: `@chtz`  Works great, thanks. All of them will return an expression and then _lazily evaluated_ when `T2n<2> t22_1` is constructed. What do you mean by _lazy expression_? Thanks.

Comment: See e.g., if you do `auto r = a & b;` and then print `r`, then modify `a` or `b` and print `r` again.

Comment: [chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870253/chtz). Got it, with `T2n<2> r = a & b`, `r` contains the result - in this case, I assume that RHS is still an expression, but lazily evaluated. With `auto r = ...`, it always remains an expression till it is used. Pretty neat!